# How to fix "No gene can be mapped, Expected input gene ID, return NULL..." error in clusterProfiler?

Tags: r, bioconductor, clusterprofiler

I am trying EnrichKEGG on a few gene samples of genes to check it works before inputting the full genome:

This is my data input as test.csv

```
id,fc
AJAP_14870,-0.04
AJAP_14875,0.32
AJAP_14880,-0.06
AJAP_14885,0.15
AJAP_14890,-0.52
AJAP_14895,-0.39
AJAP_14900,0.16
```

```r
geneList = test[,2]
names(geneList) = as.character(test[,1])
geneList = sort(geneList, decreasing = TRUE)

mygene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]

kk <- enrichKEGG(gene         = mygene,
                 organism     = 'aja',
                 pvalueCutoff = 0.05)
```

There are no spaces in the gene names, I tested via

```r
print(head(test$ID), quote=TRUE)
```

But I get the error

```r
--> No gene can be mapped....
--> Expected input gene ID:
--> return NULL...
```

I also tried installing through other means

```r
getOption("clusterProfiler.download.method")
#[1] "libcurl"
install.packages("R.utils")
library(R.utils)
R.utils::setOption("clusterProfiler.download.method","auto")
```

but that gives me the same error when I run the code. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code produces no error on my machine, what is your clusterProfiler version ?

Comment: @Basti Thanks so much for getting back to me!!

> packageVersion("clusterProfiler")
[1] ‘4.2.2’

Comment: Maybe you could try `BiocManager::install("clusterProfiler", force = TRUE)`as mine is ‘4.7.1’ and restart your R session

Comment: @Basti Thanks for this! I tried that but it still just says version 4.2.2??

Comment: Could you share your sessionInfo() in your post ? Maybe your R version or Bioconductor version is incompatible with latest clusterProfiler version.

Comment: @Basti you're absolutely right - I've just had to update rtools, biocmanager and R! It's working now! Thanks so much for your help!! The relief haha

Comment: No worries, I hope you will get good results!

Comment: @Basti, would you mind converting your comments to an answer? It would be more visible.

Answer (score 3):

This issue may arise with earlier versions of clusterProfiler.

A solution is to re-install clusterProfiler : `BiocManager::install("clusterProfiler", force = TRUE)`

Pay attention that updating your R or Bioconductor (and restart your R session) version may be needed as noted in the comments

Answer (score 1):

`enrichKEGG()` expects entrez gene IDs so you will need to convert your gene identifiers to entrez identifiers first.

EDIT: Please see the answer by @Basti.

Comment: I've used this code previously and it has only worked using the locus_tags as thats what is input into KEGG for aja as far as I'm aware? Really confused why its not working now?